# Generalizing Algebraic Problem

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, estimation

> Molly went to the store to purchase ink pens. She found three kinds of
> pens. The first cost $4$ dollars each; the price of the second kind was
> $4$ for $1$ dollar, and the cost for the third kind was $2$ for $1$ dollar
> (note it is possible to buy all types of pens individually if
> desired). She bought $20$ pens and she bought at least one of each kind.
> The cost was $20$ dollars. When she got back to her office, Molly
> decided to turn this into a math problem. She asked: Given the cost
> was $20$ dollars, how many of each ink of pen did I buy?
>
> 1. How many pens of each kind did she buy?
> 2. Show that the purchase you selected will cost $20$ dollars for $20$ pens and determine whether there is more than one answer to the question or
>    just one answer.
> 3. Provide an explanation that shows how you solved the problem, including the question to whether or not there is more than one
>    answer.

I'm stuck because all I want to do is list out all of the pens. Would an option be $4x+.5y+.25z=20$? Since pens are worth either $\$4.25$ cents or $50$ cents.  How can I generalize this?

Comment: What are the possibilities for the $\$4$ pen? Do all of them work? Do any of them work? Which one(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need another equation. Since the number of pens equals 20, you then must also have x+y+z=20. From there, you need to find values of x, y, and z such that both equations are fulfilled.